# Non-autocomplete Widget for Term Reference Fields on Content Type

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities, ajax

The available options at the moment are `Autocomplete term widget (tagging)`, `Select list` and `Check boxes/radio buttons`, but I'd like to use a widget without autocomplete.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To clarify: I'd like to use a widget where you're able to add comma separated tags, just like the current one, but without ajax.

Comment: An easy way might be to set it as autocomplete and then just unset() the ['#ajax'] part in a form_alter.

Comment: Not sure I understand - as you've already mentioned you can choose 'Select list' or 'Check boxes/radio buttons' as an alternative to the autocomplete widget. Neither of those have autocomplete

Comment: @Clive I edited the question.

Comment: @2pha That would probably work. Do you think you could help me with that? I'm not very good with code :)

Comment: The hooks you will probably want to use is hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter documented at: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7. Then all you need to do is unset() the specific ['#ajax'] item in the $form array. Without knowing your specific form id or the field id that you want to change, I really can't give any code that would be helpful. Why do you want to disable the autocomplete anyway?

Comment: @2pha Thanks, I will take a closer look soon :) Users are supposed to add existing or new tags when they upload content. I don't need the autocomplete function, and if you save the content while the ajax is working you get the popup error.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the @2pha suggestion:

```
function MODULENAME_form_CONTENTTYPE_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_name']['#ajax'] = FALSE;
}
```